# App is reload If click firebase notification when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

When app is running and notification is alert if I click it ,notification is go to there (`onMessageReceived` is running)

but when app is in background and notification is alert if I click it, App is reload again (at first such as splash screen) ,not go to there and `onMessageReceived` is not running

How to fix it?

ps. sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the required activity as intent, not the MainActivity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

Give activity name to pending intent ....

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationCheck.class);       
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("App Name")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code. I am using that and it is opening my HomeActivity.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
//change HomeActivity.class which activity you want to open after clicking notification
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

change HomeActivity.class which activity you want to open after clicking notification.. hope it will work...

Comment: my app when app is in background, and notification is alert if I click it, onMessageReceived is not running

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798456/onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-is-in-the-background

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

You can check app is in the background or not and then in MyFirebaseMessagingService class you can use this method in for handle message and handle the notification.

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: where is class to push  method `isAppIsInBackground`

Comment: put this method in NotificationUtils class and then you can use this in MyFirebaseMessagingService class.