# Android notification dont open activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that sends/receives notification using Firebase. Im sending the notification with no problem, but if the app is open the notification display an square instead of the smallicon also if i click the notification nothing happens, but if i'm using a different app i receive the notification and the notification show the correct icon and also opens the app.

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); 
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message) { 

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifitcation")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        manager.notify(999, builder.build());
    }
}



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    String title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel("MyNotifitcation", "MyNotifitcation", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("general").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                String msg = "Successfull";
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    msg = "Failed";
                }
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean when notification is clicked, it doesn't intent to specific activity?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes, but only this happens only if the app is open

Answer (score 0):

For Notification click add Pending intent to notification builder. and for  adding image/icon to notification use setSmallIcon() in notification builder. below is my notification code.

```
private void sendNotification(String body, String title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("action_type", "notify");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"channel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
//                .setContent(contentView)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("body")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code. Opening Activity.
 [original post credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796075/app-is-reload-if-click-firebase-notification-when-app-is-in-background/44796241#44796241)

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```